# Destructuring in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is there a nicer way of achieving this using destructuring in es6?

```
  searchCreated(searchParams) {
    this.regionId = searchParams.region;
    this.maxPrice = searchParams.maxPrice;
    this.minPrice = searchParams.minPrice;
    this.selectedLocalities = searchParams.selectedLocalities;
    this.propertyTypeId = searchParams.propertyTypeId;
    this.minBeds = searchParams.minBeds;
    this.maxBeds = searchParams.maxBeds;
    this.minSize = searchParams.minSize;
    this.maxSize = searchParams.maxSize;
    this.keyword = searchParams.keyword;
    this.ber = searchParams.ber;
}
```

If all those values were on their own rather than properties of the `this` I'd be fine. I'm just not sure of an elegant way of effectively mapping one object onto another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are adding all of `searchParam`'s properties to `this`, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which basically copies an object's properties to another object.

In your code, it would look like so:

```
searchCreated(searchParams) {
    Object.assign(this, searchParams, { // additional object for custom params
        region: searchParams.regionId,
        customParamName: searchParams.customParam
    }); 
}
```

Comment: There are edge cases where property name don't always match: `this.regionId = searchParams.region;`

Comment: @Kunukn if that's the case, I would recommend keeping your interface/model signature in sync, or use getters for one-offs.

Comment: We can still make use of `Object.assign` by passing an additional object with the edge cases explicitly stated. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah that was an issue.  However, I have another issue now.  If there isn't a property specified in the searchParams object I need it to still be assigned to this, but as null.  So for instance, on one search the maxPrice could be set in searchParams, but then on the second search if maxPrice isnt specificed I need it to be null on the this object rather than the previous value

Comment: Ah, if you need `undefined` values to be converted to `null`, there's no avoiding listing out every parameter that you want to copy over to `this`. Ideally, `searchParams` would come ready with `null` values. But in order for that to happen, you'd need to write an intermediary function, and would therefore still need to list out all the properties and map `undefined` ones to `null` somewhere in your code.

Comment: you copy to much. Maybe something like this to fix it. `Object.assign(this, searchParams, { 
        regionId: searchParams.region,
        region: undefined /*cleanup to much copy*/
    }); `

Comment: Or delete them again like this. Not sure what is most elegant.
`Object.assign(this, searchParams, { 
        regionId: searchParams.region
    }); 
delete this.region;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [object rest](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) to collect all props except those that need renaming. You can [assign new names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) while destructuring. Then use Object#assign to merge everything into `this`.

Note: object rest/spread is still a proposal, and it requires a [babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) to work.

```
searchCreated({ region: regionId, ...otherProps }) {
    return Object.assign(this, otherProps, { regionId });
}
```